# How to reshape Numpy array after applying n.where?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, array-broadcasting

I have `output` and `imarray`, both have the same shapes. In the following code, I want to color the specific pixels to `colors[0]`:

```
colors = [[0,0,255],[0,255,0]]
output[np.where((imarray >= values[0])&(imarray <= values[1]))] = colors[0]
```

but it gives an error as the `output` array is flattened to the shape of `(4413,)`. The error is:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (4413,)
```

Comment: Simply skip the `np.where` wrapper?

Comment: I don't understand, how?

Comment: `output[(imarray >= values[0])&(imarray <= values[1])] = colors[0]`?

Comment: This again creates a flattened array.

Comment: That assigns into `output`. I don't see any creation there.

Comment: Advanced indexing, whether with a boolean mask or its `where` returns a flattened array.  I was thinking it might be selecting 1471 pixels: 4413 is 3*1471.  Is `values[0]` shape (3,)?

Answer (score 0):

Make a 3 color image array:

```
In [453]: arr = np.random.randint(0,256,(10,10,3))                                                           
In [454]: arr1=arr.copy()
```

Now apply a `where` mask, comparing the values with some 'color':

```
In [455]: arr1[np.where(arr >= [100,100,100])].shape                                                         
Out[455]: (188,)
In [456]: 188/3                                                                                              
Out[456]: 62.666666666666664
```

In your example the mask selected a modules 3 set of elements, but here that isn't the case.  It's selecting array elements from a mix of pixels.  I suspect that you/we really want the pixels that satisfy some color combination.  To do that we need to use `all` or `any` to reduce the mask to 2d - to pixels

```
In [457]: np.where(np.all(arr >= [100,100,100],2))                                                           
Out[457]: 
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9]),
 array([2, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 5, 6, 3, 8, 4, 8, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6]))

In [458]: arr1[_457] = [0,0,255]
```

This works because `arr1[Out[457]]` is (21,3) - 21 pixels.  `np.array([0,0,255])` is (3,) which broadcasts to (21,3).

---

Compare the set of pixels selected with the `all` mask:

```
In [460]: arr1[_457]                                                                                         
Out[460]: 
array([[  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255],
       [  0,   0, 255]])
```

to the set of array values selected with the 3d mask:

```
In [461]: arr1[np.where(arr >= [100,100,100])]                                                               
Out[461]: 
array([145, 250, 198,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0, 255, 249, 208, 179, 184,
       100, 128, 219, 217, 128, 202, 200, 127, 118, 149, 236, 199, 136,
       110, 170, 199,   0,   0, 255, 128, 252, 193, 210,   0,   0, 255,
         0,   0, 255, 151, 163,   0,   0, 255, 212, 109, 187, 202, 129,
       110, 206, 137, 219, 227, 115, 130, 150, 201, 190, 231,   0,   0,
       255,   0,   0, 255, 236, 146, 113, 204, 221, 144, 128, 205, 181,
       114,   0,   0, 255, 219, 200, 197, 189, 141, 226, 248,   0,   0,
       255, 218, 245, 180, 251, 140, 253,   0,   0, 255, 143, 147, 143,
       245,   0,   0, 255, 235, 253, 165, 234, 205, 105, 122,   0,   0,
       255, 162, 149, 200, 202, 142, 208, 133, 254, 119, 205, 111,   0,
         0, 255,   0,   0, 255, 180, 158,   0,   0, 255, 170, 205, 103,
       122, 238, 104, 177, 172, 189, 192, 194,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,
       255,   0,   0, 255, 143, 224, 213, 159, 182, 148, 168, 237, 127,
       233, 230, 244, 172, 216, 107,   0,   0, 255, 111, 254,   0,   0,
       255, 246, 148, 223, 174, 199])
```

The values are all 100 or up, except the ones we modified, but we can't tell which belong to which pixel.